# Failure in executing shell script producing output on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bash, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have had a hard time in executing my shell scripts on bash on Ubuntu on windows 10. The script is very simple:

```
# file name: submission.sh
echo "Hello world" > output.txt
```

When I executed it with a command `sh submission.sh`, it gave me an error:

```
$ sh submission.sh
: Directory nonexistentssion.sh: cannot create output.txt
```

However, when I changed the script into

```
# file name: submission.sh
echo "Hello world"
```

and executed it with the same command `sh submission.sh`, it gave me the right output

```
$ sh submission.sh
Hello world
```

It seems like bash on Ubuntu on Windows cannot get it right when the script involves directing the output to a file. Is there any solution or workaround to this?

**EDIT:**
Details on my system:

- Program: "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"
- OS: Windows 10 Version 1709

**EDIT:**
Typing the command directly on the terminal works, i.e.

```
$ echo "Hello world" > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
Hello world
```

I still wants to put the commands on a file and execute the file instead of writing the command directly to the terminal, and this is still unsolved.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: You appear to have mangled text in `nonexistentssion.sh:` and `No such file or directorytput.txt` which suggests you might have Windows line-endings in the file `\r`.  If you created the script using a Windows program (like Notepad) then that could be the case.  If you have `dos2unix` then run it on your script and try again.

Comment: @cdarke yeah, you are right. It works now. That's strange because I edited it using `nano` from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, so I thought they are using `\n` for the line ending. If you'd like to write a proper answer, I would be happily to accept it.

Comment: @Firman: made into  question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have mangled text in `nonexistentssion.sh:` and `No such file or directorytput.txt` which suggests you might have Windows line-endings in the file `\r`. If you created the script using a Windows program (like Notepad) then that could be the case.

If you have `dos2unix` then run it on your script and try again.

By the way for future reference, running `sh` is not the same as running `bash`.  In this case it would have made no difference, but `sh` is a POSIX shell, full `bash` has many extensions which will not work under `sh`.

Some platforms run `sh` as a symbolic link to `bash` which fools people into thinking they are the same, but `bash` detects this and switches to POSIX mode when running as `sh`.   It is a common issue here.

Answer (score 0):

In your `submission.sh` file, is better to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as first line.
Another thing you want to consider if you want to use `sh` instead of `bash` is to replace `echo` with `printf`, for portability

Your code should look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Hello world!\n" > output.txt
```

You can call it simply by `./submission.sh` and because of the shebang, your terminal will know how to open it [:

P.S. Keep in mind that because of the standard umask in Ubuntu, you might want to execute `chmod u+x submission.sh` before running it.

Also, notice that your error is probably caused by a permissions issue.
Try adding write permissions in the folder you are launching the script.

Comment: That still does not work. `: No such file or directorytput.txt`. I have all the permissions (`rwx`) on that folder, so I suspect the problem actually lies on bash on Ubuntu on Windows. I have tried it on an Ubuntu machine (not Ubuntu on Windows) and it works really well.

Comment: Maybe you want to provide further infos?
Like name of the program, version, os used...
For example, if you are using gitbash, redirection is not supported.

Comment: I have put it on my post. It is "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" using Windows 10 version 1709.

Comment: This might be due to Windows permissions being different from WSL/Ubuntu permissions. Is your current directory in /mnt/c subdirectory or / subdirectory?